# Resource Usage Column for Sandbox Solutions solutions

Tags: sandbox-solution

I'm working in a sandbox solution and I have a solution uploaded to a site collection.

In that _catalogs/solution/ folder there is a column called Resource Usage.  I know from MSDN that each "point" corresponds to a particular set of conditions that occur because of a resource going above a threshold.

My question is, is the Resource Usage column the total amount of point resources being used by the solution for the day (aka till the timer job goes off) or is it the total amount of point resources per user that uses the solution?

This is probably a trivial question, but I can't find a definitive answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource points are a total for all the sandboxed solutions for the entire site collection. Unfortunately this means that even a well behaved sandboxed solution will be stopped if other sandboxed solutions are consuming too many points that day.

Comment: Certainly for the bar at the top of the solutions list, but what about the value of the column "Resource Usage" ?  Is that the total points per timer job?

Comment: The Resource Usage column shows the usage for each solution (not per user), so you can use that to see which solutions are misbehaving, but note that the daily threshold is for the total.

Answer (score 0):

Points are per solution, not per user.